# Will Ubuntu and Kubuntu both be upgraded?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I have both KDE and Gnome installed on my desktop. If I upgrade to 10.10 will both desktops, KDE and Gnome, be upgraded too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a system upgrade will upgrade all packages including KDE and Gnome, no matter whether you're using Ubuntu or Kubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all installed packages should be updated when you switch to 10.10. Unless, of course, 10.10 does not have newer versions of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you can do the same from a fresh installation. Just back up your installed package list to  a text file using Synaptic. Go to File, Save Markings (tick box save full state). Copy the file to a usb key or somewhere safe. Re-install and then open Synaptic and choose Read markings and point to the text file. Come back when Synaptic is done and you have things back to normal.

I know that you asked about upgrades, but they don't always work out and fresh installations are always better because in my experience, they never fail. :)